# Converting a date variable into a character variable in SAS

Tags: date, sas, character, converters

I have a date variable currently formatted as **date9** that I want to convert into a specific character format.

I would like a date value of `02DEC2013` to be shown like this: `021213`, in character format.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Please show that you have at least put in some effort and research prior to asking on SO.

Comment: Use the "ddmmyy6." format

Comment: Well I hadn't tried anything, because I didn't have a clue what to do. I ended up doing this: pbgtp0=compress(20||substr(startdato,5,2)||substr(startdato,3,2)||substr(startdato,1,2));
pbgtp=pbgtp0*1; - and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about any inbuilt SAS format which would provide the result in the format you are expecting, but below code might help you out!

```
data _null_;
Input_='02DEC2013'd;
output_=put(put(day(Input_),z2.)||put(month(Input_),z2.)||substr(left(year(Input_)),3,2),$6.);
put output_=;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `put` function will convert numeric to character with formatting intact; so a numeric date will become fixed as a character pretty easily.

The other portion you are looking for is the correct date format. Looks like this one: `MMDDYYNw.` will meet your needs.

Have fun!

Comment: If I write startdato2=put(startdato); in a datastep (I want startdato which has date9. format to become character value in startdato2), SAS give the error:ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

Comment: data temp;
 format startdato date9.;
 startdato = '09Jun12'd;
run;

You also need to add the format.

data temp2;
 set temp;
 startdato2 = put(startdato,date9.);
run;

Comment: When i run your exampleit works, but when i use it on my own data startdato2 is still in date9. format? data test;
format startdato date9.;
set begge_steder_kobl2;
startdato2 = put(startdato,date9.);
run;

Comment: If startdato2 is already defined on the dataset, the put will not change the format. Make sure to drop it from the dataset if it already exists.

Comment: ahh it was converted, but the format was not the way I wanted it. 09Jun12 shound be 090612 - 06 in stead of jun. Adn I want it to be 12 in stead of 2012

Comment: DDMMYY instead of MMDDYY.

Comment: Hmmm... try DDMMYYBw. format and then remove the spaces with compress function outside of put statement.

i.e. startdato2 = compress(put(startdato,DDMMYYBw.))